# How can i identify the indexing while doing expand/Collapse in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

This is my following code while doing expand / Collapse but i just want to identify the indexing when i do expand / Collapse operation in that.

Could you please give me the sample code for that.

```
     $("#accordionDemo2").accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });

    <p><h2>Hi, This is Multiple Panel Demo1</h2></p>
    <div id="accordionDemo2">
        <h3><a href="#" class="acc">Section 1</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Hi, This is Section 1</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#" class="acc">Section 2</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Hi, This is Section 2</p>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#" class="acc">Section 3</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Hi, This is Section 3</p>        
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#" class="acc">Section 4</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Hi, This is Section 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active

Selector for the active element. Set to false to display none at start. Needs collapsible: true.

```
//getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

Comment: var accordionLength = $('.Panel').length;
    for (var j = 1; j <= accordionLength; j++) {
 
        $("#accordion" + j).accordion({ collapsible: true, autoHeight: true, active: false });
    }

Comment: Maybe try $('#accordionDemo2 .acc').length instat of .Panel; because in your code example at the top there is no .Panel class. To realy help you it would be great if you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: while loading the page by default its expanded mode ..but i want to capture after the page is being loaded then i will do expand and collapse operation..

Comment: $("#accordionDemo2").accordion({
            collapsible: true, active: false
        }); to don`t display an open accordion

Comment: Then after how can i identify the uniquiness while doing exapand /collapse